XML Serializer remove XML definition
How do we remove XML definition () when we serialize List object to xml in C#?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>


Use XmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration, and pass in the XmlWriterSettings instance when instantiating your XmlWriter.
Copied & pasted example from the link:
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;

writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, settings);

writer.WriteStartElement("order");
writer.WriteAttributeString("orderID", "367A54");
writer.WriteAttributeString("date", "2001-05-03");
writer.WriteElementString("price", "19.95");
writer.WriteEndElement();
    
writer.Flush();


OP apparently wanted this xml generated to a string that OP could pass back in an API response.
string result;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;

    writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings);

    writer.WriteStartElement("order");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("orderID", "367A54");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("date", "2001-05-03");
    writer.WriteElementString("price", "19.95");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    
    writer.Flush();
    result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}



I am using Stringbuilder to write it as API response, i don't need to create a physical XML file. So it doesn't have OmitXmlDeclaration. Is there any other way??

I didn't see a code snippet in the original post or anything mentioning a string builder.  Did you perhaps want to include an MCVE that we could help with?

XmlWriterSettings did help in my scenario
